# How to synchronize this special case of threads with C++ std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, thread-synchronization, stdmutex

I need some help for following case: I have a main program that starts multiple instances of the same function as threads. The function that gets called is split in at least two parts. First, every instance has to do that **Part 1** of the function before they can continue with **Part 2**. Here I need to synchronize them. To make it easier to understandable, I will write some example code:

```
void TMainForm::foo(int numThreads)
{
    std::cout << "Part 1: do some work" << std::endl;

    /* HERE NEEDS TO BE SOMETHING THAT CHECKS WHETHER EVERY INSTANCE HAS DONE PART 1 !!*/

    std::cout << "Part 2: do some work" << std::endl;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void TMainForm::StartingThreads()
{
    int threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    std::vector<std::thread> t(threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        t[i] = std::thread(foo, threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
        t[i].join();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to use a mutex lock but it didn't work for me. I incremented a atomic variable (lets say **atomic a**) and if the value was smaller than **numThreads** I did **mutex::lock**. When the last instance would have done it's work, it would have done a **mutex::unlock**. But my threads did always stuck after **Part 1**.

Does anybody has some idea?

Comment: I suspect you want to use a [barrier](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/std-barrier-in-cpp-20/).

Comment: refactor to have the two parts in seperate functions. Then first have some threads work on part 1, join them all, them make some threads work on part 2

Comment: Use [`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch) (or `std::barrier`, which is a multi-use latch).

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I haven't heard about **std::latch**. This seems to be the right thing for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you can upgrade to C++20 - which is the case if you access `std::latch`/`std::barrier` - then consider using `std::jthread` over `std::thread`; the former `join`s automatically on destruction.

Comment: Pre C++20: Increment the atomic variable and enter a spin/yield loop while waiting for the atomic variable to reach the correct value. Alternatively, use a condition variable and `notify_all` when the atomic variable has reached the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using C++ 20, then other folks have given you an answer. If you're on 17 or older, then I would make a class that you can unit test like crazy.

```
class Barrier {
public:
    Barrier(int dc = 1): desiredCount(dc) {}

    void done() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        ++doneCount;
        condVar.notify_all();
    }

    void waitReady() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        while (doneCount < desiredCount) {
            condVar.wait(lock);           
        }
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::cond_var condVar;
    int desiredCount = 1;
    int doneCount = 0;
};
```

Then in your code, have one of these, initialized to the thread count, then in the threads:

```
barrier.done();
barrier.waitReady();
```

I'm writing this in place -- may not be perfect code. There are other ways to use wait (you can pass a predicate), but this is the pattern I always use.

Comment: Thanks! That looks also very good to me, especially with older c++ versions! I guess in your **done()** function you want to increment the **doneCount** instead of the **desiredCount**? I cannot give you an upvote because I'm new here.

Comment: @TommyBe You're right about the done() method, and I'll fix that.